How to manage large datas in Python?
This is somewhat a generic question about managing large datasets in python
I have a few experiences working with python but I have never managed a large amount of data before, so I am pretty new in this problem.
I have a set of images of shape 512x512x135x50 that I would like to manipulate in torch. Specially, I need to apply somme Fourier Transform Operation over the 135-sized dimension. Initially, I managed to vectorized over each pixel, so doing it in the whole image is not so much of a problem. However, I found some trouble vectorizing it in the last dimension so the code ends up taking too much time.
Additionally, I have been facing some memory issues as the data set itself has around 7 Gb, which makes storing some of the results a problem.
Doing some research, I have encountered a lot of texts recommending batch techniques to overcome this memory issue. Instead of performing operations in all images at one time, it would be more efficient to do it in a small portion of the ensemble.
My main question is : how should I choose my batch size to optimize the consuming memory of my program ?
My code would be something like this :

NFRAMES = 50 #number of frames
for jj,FRAME in enumerate(torch.arange(NFRAMES)): 
    IMAGES_PATH = ALL_IMAGES_PATH\[FRAME \* n_k0 : FRAME\*n_k0 + n_k0\] # Setting the respective 135 images path of frame jj
    for ii,path in enumerate(IMAGES_PATH):
        image_k\[...,ii\] = transforms.ToTensor()(Image.open(path)) #collecting images 
        intensity_z = torch.fft.ifft(image_k, dim = -1)   #fft operation
        intensity_z\[...,index \< 2\] = 0 # filtering
        intensity_z\[...,index \> 70\] = 0 #filtering
        phase_profile_map\[...,jj\] = torch.from_numpy(np.unwrap(intensity_z.angle())) #getting angle


I was hoping to do all this operation faster than now and specially construct the phase_profile_map variable (512 x 512 x 135 x 50) by batching because i believe that applying fft in image_k (512 x 512 x 135) and storing in intensity_z (512 x 512 x 135) is not optimal and takes too much memory. So I was hopping on getting some tips on the how to approach this problem in python ...

Could you create minimal, reproducible example. I have trouble understanding what is your problem and what is "not so much of a problem". Another thing, what are all those backslashes for?

Yeah I am sorry, I think my question does not bring any really fruitful discussion because it is too general I suppose . But in reality I would like to learn methods in Python to understand how to improve time and memory performance when dealing with large data sets (in my case tensor of size 512x512x135x50). On the other hand, I do not know I there are backslashes in my code snippet. I just copied from my notebook.
